# Clear cached (not saved!) network passwords without reboot

Tags: windows-7, networking, passwords

I have a accessed a network share and Windows 7 asked me for a password. I entered the password and did NOT check the "Remember my credentials" check box.

So the credentials cannot be found in the credential manager (control keymgr.dll).
And since they show not up there, I cannot delete them from there.

At first net use showed the connection but calling net use /delete removed it from there but still my password is saved.

net session shows nothing...

Also deleting IE history did not delete the password.

So my question is: What can I do (without rebooting the computer) to remove this cached password?

EDIT: Open File explorer > Tools > Disconnect network drive also does not show that connection...

Comment: Running this command and waiting a little while should do it **`NET USE \\10.0.0.4\F /DELETE`**. Give it a shot and let me know. My [answer here](http://superuser.com/questions/1030469/windows-remove-password-used-to-connect-to-shared-drives/1030478#1030478) on a similar question has more detail

Comment: Note to close voters: it's entirely clear what the question is asking; it wants to remove cached credentials used to connect to other computers. I'm voting Leave Open.

Comment: So it doesn't work at all even when waiting for a delay period as indicated in the link of my answer there? That link has three bullet points so just take a look to confirm none work as well as anything indicated such as wait period, etc.

Answer (score 3):

The cached password is actually a cached Kerberos ticket with your domain controller. To remove the cached 'session' open an elevated command prompt and type in klist purge
After you do this open Windows Explorer and browse to the share once more, you should be prompted for credentials.
The problem with this may be that you will kill all sessions using a Kerberos ticket for authentication. So all shares will re-authenticate, which usually happens in the background anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Another method, that works also with XP (and some older version).

Open a command prompt (with Vista or newer must be elevated / as Administrator)
do this command:

```
net use
```

you get the list of saved connections AND of open sessions

```
c:\>net use
New connections will be remembered.
Status       Local     Remote                    Network
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Unavailable  J:        \\server\storedname       Microsoft Windows Network
Disconnected           \\server\IPC$             Microsoft Windows Network
The command completed successfully.
```

The "\server\IPC$" name is the session of which the password is remembered!
Now with the command

```
net use \\server\IPC$ /delete
```

you will delete the cached password without the need of a logout!