# Windows - Remove password used to connect to shared drives

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, window

Good day all

I've been looking around and I can't find a solution for this.

Consider this:

- My IP - 10.0.0.4
- My External Harddrive is shared with letter F:

Thus running

> \\10.0.0.4\F

will connect to that drive and show that which is shared. (*this is done without having checked the remember user box, thus it will not remember the username and password*)

After I have done that which I had to, I close the

> "\10.0.0.30\F" Window

After which I run the connect to ^ command again, but I reconnect with no user/pass request

**How do I remove this/show a user and pass popup?**

**What I have tried:**

User Accounts>Manage Credentials> nothing of the sort there

cmd>net user, net account,etc. nothing

any other recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Windows - Remove password used to connect to shared drives**
>
> > \10.0.0.4\F
>
> will connect to that drive and show that which is shared. (this is
>   done without having checked the remember user box, thus it will not
>   remember the username and password)
>
> After which I run the connect to ^ command again, but I reconnect with
>   no user/pass request
>
> **How do I remove this/show a user and pass popup?**

There may be a few things to check to delete a cached credential on Windows 7 actually so I'll list in the order you would want to try but #1 seems to work for me just fine when testing just as you explained; however, I noticed what appeared to be applicable credentials in the #2 and #3 below items as well.

1. From a command prompt type in `NET USE \\10.0.0.4\F /DELETE` and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

   - It seems there is a ***delay*** on this so you may need to wait a few minutes for it to become effective or at least when I tested it seemed to take a few minutes before the `\\servername\sharename` started prompting me again for username and password
2. From Start Run type in `control /name Microsoft.CredentialManager`
   and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

   - This is the same as `Control Panel` -> `Credential Manager`
3. From a command prompt type in `C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe keymgr.dll, KRShowKeyMgr` and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

   - Select <kbd>Edit</kbd> to see the detail of each entry and <kbd>Remove</kbd> what you confirm needs removed.