# Delete login credetials on network folder (windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, network-shares, share-credentials

I have a network folder. The login credentials changed, and I can't reenter them. I tryed google the solution but `net use * /d` is not working. It deletes the cache, but then black magic happens, and the old ones are instantly rewritten there, if I try to open the network folder.

```
C:\Users\*********>net use
A rendszer tárolja az új kapcsolatokat.

A listában nincsenek bejegyzések.
```

After aptemting to open the folder:

```
C:\Users\*************>net use
A rendszer tárolja az új kapcsolatokat.


Állapot      Helyi     Távoli                    Hálózat

 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
OK                     \\**.*.*.***\server       Microsoft Windows Network
```

But these are the old credentials.

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Try running `net use * /delete /y` and see if that makes any difference

Comment: Still not working, it's like after I delete it, something rewrites the credentials from somewhere.

Comment: Did you check if the credentials are saved under Control panel -> Credential  Manager?

Comment: Look here and check these method all that I mention: https://superuser.com/questions/1030469/windows-remove-password-used-to-connect-to-shared-drives/1030478#1030478

Comment: Elias I've checked it, and nope. McDonald's i've tryed all 3, and nope, it doesen't appear. If I try to open it, still says that i have no permission, and i can't give the right credentials.

Answer (score 1):

Issue the:

```
    net use * /delete /yes
```

And then try and see if you can force the proper credentials with:

```
    net use \\servername /user:\\servername\username password
```

For example, my test user name, password, and server are: cjohnson Password1234 and \\dev respectively.

```
    net use \\dev /user:dev\cjohnson Password1234
```

Comment: Unfortunately net use is very inconsistent. Even after deleting all credentials I can access my SMB shares, credentialed as I was before... It's forever been buggy and unreliable in Windows 10, just try and write a script that relies on it and watch it randomly fail to work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
net use \\**.*.*.***\server /d /PERSISTENT:YES
```